# Requesting the complete guide to lock down/password require windows 10 when inactive

Tags: windows-10, passwords, lock, energy-saving

My win 10 is set to start screen saver after 2 mins and put monitor to turn off monitor after 15 mins. Password is required on resume from screen saver. I want it to work for example incase I forgot the windows key + L.

But sometimes it works and sometimes it does not. I am really frustrated that I cannot trust that windows locks itself when inactive for a time. The reason I suspect could be some updates that are pending like GPU driver or software updates (noticed when I updated the software/driver and restarted that the lock screen requires passwords). Or it could be that I have some google chrome tabs that plays a video I am unaware about. I don't want to have to set my computer to sleep just to enforce the password request. Plain and simple wants the require passwords to work when screen is locked or monitor goes into sleep.

For whatever the reasons. It is really frustrating not being able to trust windows. Now I'm requesting config settings to completely overrides everything to make sure that the lock screen and the password is required everytime it's inactive.

Answer (score 2):

The way to be 100% sure that Windows is locked when you walk away is to press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

If you are in a shared environment then even 2 minutes is easily long enough for someone to notice you have gone and start abusing your account. You should not count on it as a security practice and the timeout is there to *help* you, not as your first line of defense. If you don't trust Windows then it sounds like you trust your colleagues even less.

Comment: I use it at home. If I forgot to lock manually I would want it to lock down for me. It works on mac and linux. One would want to expect it to just work as it concerns security. If you don't have a good answer, just comment.

Comment: To me this *is* a good answer. Android acts in the same way, a wakelock can prevent the system from turning off the screen because YouTube or some browser is playing video and the system has no way to know if it is desired. Would you consider it "okay" for the system to lock itself just because you watched a YouTube video for 2 minutes and took your hand off the mouse while it was playing? I doubt you would... manually locking it *guarantees* desired behaviour. Windows is more tablet friendly than Linux or MacOS and so they chose to support tablet style wakelock features.